# How to make fixed navigation menus?

Tags: html, css, menu, css-position

I would like to make a HTML/CSS menu which is fixed when I scroll down.

I have tried:

```
<ul id=menu>
<li><a href="#L384">Section 1</a>
<li><a href="#details">Section 2</a>
<li><a href="#FAQ">Section 3</a>
</ul>
```

```
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 8em;
  margin-top: -2.5em;
}
```

Comment: you definitely put much effort in your "trying", since you copied just this code, right? http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/menus :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't quite understand what you try to accomplish, but try this:

```
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```